# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Cosmos.framework/Cosmos

Tags: promise, cocoapods, device, dyld, rpath

Recently after I added some libraries I couldn't build & run my project on my personal iPhone device because of the reason below!

I've google it and searched everywhere for the solution but I gave up :(

**So, Anyone can help me please?**

My pod file contents:

> pod 'Firebase/Auth' pod 'SDWebImage'

--

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/E-Store
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=25
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/627A9DC9-A2C9-475C-AAD5-2E696D8772BC/E-Store.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
```

(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

What probably happened (for anyone still looking) is that after running

```
pod install
```

in your project's directory, you are still building the ".xcodeproj" file instead of running the newly created ".xcworkspace" from the pod install. Remember, after pod installing, you MUST do edits on and work with the .xcworkspace instead.